# React Router and Redux, re-enabling a `loading` flag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Since there is a lot of code involved I'll describe my setup abstractly:

- I have react, redux, and react-router as described in redux [docs](https://redux.js.org/advanced/usage-with-react-router).
- I have a dynamic route (e.g. `/users/:id` ). With redux, I have an action that calls to the server and gives back the user info for rendering.
- By default, the redux store has `loading: true`, and in react I use `loading ? <Spinner /> : <User />`.
- The redux action that calls to the server dispatches the info plus `loading: false`, so that `<User />` only renders after the call to the server finishes.

I think this is fairly normal, however I have the following problem: What if I want to jump from `/users/1` to `/users/2`? The store still has `loading: false` since `/users/1` loaded alright, what should I do so that my app knows that I shouldn't render `/users/2` just yet?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion will be to look on `id` change in you route component's `componentDidUpdate` and if it changed, dispatch a redux event that will change loading state to true and will start loading of that user if needed.